# How to show message in model body if bootstrap model have no data in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display a text message in bootstrap model body if no data available in model. but it's not working to me any one can pls help on it. actually here i have some cards on model if i click on skip or done buttons every card will close and on the other hand if model have only one card when I hit on the skip or done buttons model will close automatically. but i am not able to display the text in model body .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
      .modal-body{
        height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
      }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 1</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2 ">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 2</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 3</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 4</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
                
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clscurrent').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('.removeit').remove();
      if($("#myModal").find('div.card').length==0)
        {
          $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        }
else if(){
var noData = "You don't have any task";
$(".card-body").append(noData);
}      
});
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Madhu, it's not working Is any other solution .otherwise pls show me result in Js fiddle

Comment: hi Madhu, you made some changes on script but when i skip that cards even not getting message like you don't have task pls take a look on it

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
      .modal-body{
        height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
      }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 1</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2 ">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 2</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 3</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 4</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
                
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clscurrent').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('.removeit').remove();
      if($("#myModal").find('div.card').length==0)
        {
          $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        }
else{
var noData = "You don't have any task";
$(".card-body").html(noData);
}      
});
});


</script>
</body>
</html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
      .modal-body{
        height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
      }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 1</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2 ">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 2</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 3</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 4</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
                
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clscurrent').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('.removeit').remove();
      if($("#myModal").find('div.card').length==0)
        {
          $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        }
else if($("#myModal").find(".modal-body").html()==""){
var noData = "You don't have any task";
$("#myModal").find(".modal-body").html(noData);
}      
});
});


</script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Hi Madhu, it's not working Is any other solution .otherwise pls show me result in Js fiddle

Comment: hi Madhu, you made some changes on script but when i skip that cards even not getting message like you don't have task pls take a look on it

Comment: Actually, what do you want? Are you want to show that msg for each card or the whole model?

Comment: No madhu I 've resolved it . thanks for your efforts.